# Prestashop API bad request 400

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Is there a way to know why my data can not be inserted? I get API Bad Request from my Prestashop Installation. It works for customers but it does not work for cart_rules

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the cart rules XML had a nested field, which the customer demo didn't have so using the same demo code for the cart rules was not valid. I used fiddler to post data and found out the problem.